# Converting 24-hour time to 12-hour AM/PM time. Is there any condition that will break this algorithm?

Tags: java

input example `convertToAmPm("13":"30");`

```
private String convertToAmPm(String hour, String minute) {
    final String am = "am";
    final String pm = "pm";
    String amPm = pm;
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(hour);
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            hour = "12";
            amPm = am;
            break;
        case 23:
            hour = "11";
            amPm = pm;
            break;
        case 22:
            hour = "10";
            amPm = pm;
            break;
        case 21:
            hour = "9";
            amPm = pm;
            break;
        case 20:
            hour = "8";
            amPm = pm;
            break;
        case 19:
            hour = "7";
            amPm = pm;
            break;
        case 18:
            hour = "6";
            amPm = pm;
            break;
        case 17:
            hour = "5";
            amPm = pm;
            break;
        case 16:
            hour = "4";
            amPm = pm;
            break;
        case 15:
            hour = "3";
            amPm = pm;
            break;
        case 14:
            hour = "2";
            amPm = pm;
            break;
        case 13:
            hour = "1";
            amPm = pm;
            break;

        default:
            hour = ""+i;
            break;
        }
        return hour + ":" + minute + " " + amPm;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return hour + ":" + minute;
}
```

Comment: All you need to do is subtract 12. The algorithm is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, you don't need all the switches. All you need is:

```
        int i = Integer.parseInt(hour);
        if (i > 12)
           i = i - 12;
```

... with a simple `am`/`pm` check. This will make your algorithm not only more robust (you won't ask "will it break", but also much easier to read and understand).

Comment: 12:30 is not 00:30pm

Answer (score 0):

As David said, it's an overkill to write so many cases. Below is one way you can implement it

```
private static String convertToAmPm(String hour, String minute) {       

        String amOrPm="am";
        int intHour=Integer.parseInt(hour);
        int intMinute=Integer.parseInt(minute);

        if(intHour<0 || intHour>24 || intMinute<0 || intMinute>60 ){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }           

        if(intHour>=12){            
            if(intHour!=24)
                amOrPm="pm";
            if(intHour!=12)
                intHour= Integer.parseInt(hour)-12;
        }

        return intHour+":"+intMinute+" "+amOrPm;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

All inputs where time is between 01:00 to 11:59 will give incorrect output.
By default -> String amPm should be initialized to am.

More importantly, the algorithm used is not the correct way of going about solving this problem.

Comment: What with the down-vote? What I pointed out is correct : With the current definition of convertToAmPm(); a call to it as System.out.println(convertToAmPm("01","00"));                                    gives output =>   1:00 pm